# What is the Cauchy meta distribution?

Tags: distributions, sampling, copula

I overhead a professor speak about the Cauchy meta-distribution, but I am unable to find anything about it on the web. My question is what is the Cauchy meta distribution and what is the theory behind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A meta distribution is one with normal marginals but a joint copula based on a stronger tail-dependence. So a $t_\nu$ meta distribution would be obtained by generating a multivariate-t with $\nu$ d.f. and then transforming all the marginals to normals.

See, for example, [page 5 of this document](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~baltes/ftp/metaclouds.pdf).

Of course, a Cauchy is just a $t_1$.

There's a picture of a bivariate sample from a Cauchy meta distribution on p7 of the same document, and a bunch of references further on.

You might want to work on your google-fu - I found that in very short order and I'd never heard of it before (though I was familiar with the concept once I saw what it was).

Here's [a paper I found with the same search](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~baltes/ftp/MetaDensMS.pdf)

Some R code (not the fastest way to do it):

```
library(MASS)  #for mvrnorm
n <- 10000
cauchysamp <- mvrnorm(n,mu=c(0,0),Sigma=matrix(c(1,.9,.9,1),nr=2))/rnorm(n)
a <- qnorm(pt(cauchysamp,df=1))
plot(a,cex=.5)
```

gives:

[image: my meta cauchy]

which looks like the plot on page 7 I linked to before. Note that `a[,1]` and `a[,2]` are each univariate normal. In the code, immediately before it calculates the qnorm (after the pt), you have a Cauchy copula.

Comment: nice! won't this have infinite variance?

Comment: The margins are standard normal by construction, so they have the variance of standard normal random variables.

Comment: Is there a proof for that? I always thought Cauchy and the rest of the "stable" distributions were infinitely divisible or fat tailed i.e. infinite variance/sigma

Comment: Have to break my comment in two for length. The *Cauchy* is all the things you said. The distributions here *aren't Cauchy*. The marginals are standard normal. The only thing 'unusual' about it is the bivariate distribution, specifically the manner in which the two normals are associated.

Comment: When you say 'is there proof for that' do you mean proof that the marginals are standard normal? (If so, before I explain it, are you familiar with [copulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29#The_basic_idea) at all? I can explain it without that, but my explanation will be different - and shorter - if you have some background with them). If you want more than a very brief explanation, you should think about posting a new question relating to that issue.